# Prove or disprove $\max\{a,\max\{b,c\}\}=\max\{\max\{a,b\},c\}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For and $a,b,c\in \Bbb Z, $ how can I prove or disprove
1. $\max\{a,\max\{b,c\}\}=\max\{\max\{a,b\},c\}$ and
2.  $\min\{a,\min\{b,c\}\}=\min\{\min\{a,b\},c\}$

We know that,  $\max\{a,b\}=\frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}$ and $\min\{a,b\}=\frac{a+b-|a-b|}{2}$. Is it helpful to show that above result?
Please suggest.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

These expressions are hardly helpful as they lead to (at least) as many case distinctions as a direct approach: What happens if $a\ge b\ge c$? What if $b\ge a\ge c$? And so on ...

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $\max(a,\max(b,c))=\max(a,b,c)$.

Answer (score 2):

You can also show they're equal by showing each is less than or equal to the other.

Let $x=\max\{a,\max\{b,c\}\}$ and $y=\max\{\max\{a,b\},c\}$. Then
$a\leq x$ and $b\leq\max\{b,c\}\leq x$, so $\max\{a,b\}\leq x$. Also, $c\leq\max\{b,c\}\leq x$. These imply $\max\{\max\{a,b\},c\}=y\leq x$.

An analogous argument more or less shows $x\leq y$, so $x=y$.

The same reasoning also applies when dealing with $\min$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to solve it case by case. the cases can be 
$a \leq b\leq c$ , $a \leq c\leq b$ and henceforth.